# Unity3D - Playback object array of position (with dynamic velocity)

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, position, transform, velocity

We own two objects in the scene. One follows the mouse position on the screen, and the object 2 in turn follows the route object 1 did. We are storing the positions covered by the object 1 and causing the object 2 play them.
[image]

When you run the game, an object follows the other quietly, reproducing the stored position ... but when one object's speed is changed (on mouse click increase velocity) the object 2 can not keep up, as this still following the positions already be cached in the array (including the calculations speed). Please, watch the shot video below:

YouTube: https://youtu.be/_HbP09A3cFA

```
public class Play : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform obj;
    private List<Recorder> recordList;
    private float velocity = 10.0f;
    private Transform clone;

    void Start()
    {
        recordList = new List<Recorder>();
        clone = obj;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            velocity = 20.0f;
        }
        else {
            velocity = 10.0f;
        }

        var dir = Input.mousePosition - Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward), 180 * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position += transform.right * Time.deltaTime * velocity;
        Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, Camera.main.transform.position.z);

        recordList.Insert(0, new Recorder
        {
            Position = transform.position,
            Rotation = transform.rotation,
            Velocity = velocity
        });

        var x = 8;
        if (x < recordList.Count)
        {
            clone.position = recordList[x].Position;
            clone.rotation = recordList[x].Rotation;
            clone.position += clone.right * Time.deltaTime * velocity;
        }

        if (recordList.Count > x)
            recordList.RemoveRange(x, recordList.Count - x);
    }
}

public class Recorder
{
    public Vector3 Position{get;set;}
    public Quaternion Rotation{get;set;}
    public float Velocity{get;set;}
}
```

How can we play the positions stored always with the speed of the object 1?

Summary:

- If the object 1 is slowly moving object 2 as well;
- If the object 2 is running, the object 2 should do the route at a faster speed to always follow the object 1;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you might want to consider using [`Queue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `List<T>`. I think it would be a better suited datatype as it represents a FIFO collection (first in, first out), which is how you use List anyway. You can add elements with `Enqueue(T)` to the end of the queue and always get the first item with `Dequeue()` (it also removes it). As for `Stack<T>` (the opposite), there is also a `Peek()` function which lets you "preview" the next element.

Another thing, it depends on distance and speed, but i have the feeling that storing the position of every frame could become a bit excessive (maybe im just overly concerned though)

I think the issue with your code is that you always get the 8th element of the List.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply! @yes  But, I believe you do not understand the problem... It turns out that when I increase the speed of the object 1, the object 2 can not keep up because this reading of an array already stored with the speed of the object 1 at that time. Understand the problem better?